# Approximating a function as close as we wish by interpolating polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

So yesterday in lecture one of my professors gave a proof that if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0,$ then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $p(0)=0$ and $\|f-p\|_{[a,b]}<\epsilon.$ The proof was rather complicated, and I think I've found a simpler one. Also, it doesn't require $f(0)=0.$ Could anyone verify if its correct? thank you.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

By Stone-Weierstrass chose polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n\to f$ uniformly. Then we consider $p_n+(f(0)-p_n(0)).$ Let $\epsilon\geq0$ and choose $N$ large so that for all $n\geq N$ we have $\|p_n-f\|_{[a,b]}<\epsilon/2.$ It follows that
$$\|f-(p_n+(f(0)-p_n(0)))\|_{[a,b]}\leq\|f-p_n\|_{[a,b]}+\|f(0)-p_n(0)\|_{[a,b]}$$
$$<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon.$$
Thus $p_n+(f(0)-p_n(0))\to f$ uniformly, and 
$$[p_n+(f(0)-p_n(0))](0)=f(0).$$
This completes the proof. $\blacksquare$

To add, we could generalized if we replaced $(f(0)-p_n(0))$ by 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(f(x_i)-p_n(x_i))\ell_i,$$
where $x_1,...,x_n$ are a set of nodes, and $\ell_i$ are Lagrange Basis Polynomials.

Comment: Which proof did your teacher show you ? Because some people prefer showing it the "constructive" way.

Comment: Your argument is correct. What the professor is saying is we can get $p(0)=0$ if $f(0)=0$. You have proved a more general result.

Comment: @nicomezi It was non-constructive as well. It involved approximating 

$$\frac{f}{\delta +x^2}$$

by polynomials $p_n$ using Stone-Weierstrass. Afterwards we choose an $\epsilon, $ and showed that by modifying $\delta$  and choosing $n$ large we could find a polynomial $p$ satisfying $||f-p||_{[a,b]}<\epsilon.$